# How can I get the values from a non-direct relation in Propel2?

Tags: php, propel2

I'm writing a script that loads all the news from our database using Propel2.
My current code looks as follows:

```
$news = NewsQuery::create()->find();
```

This gives me the following Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Title] => Test News
            [Content] => hueheueheeueheu
            [CreatedAt] => 2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00
            [Author] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Title] => gfdgdsfgfdg
            [Content] => sdfgfdgfdgfdgf
            [CreatedAt] => 2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00
            [Author] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 3
            [Title] => abcdef
            [Content] => ghijklm
            [CreatedAt] => 2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00
            [Author] => 3
        )

)
```

As seen in the output above, the `Author` column returns the `ID` of the user that added it (via a relation to the `Users` table).
My goal is to get the `Firstname` and `Lastname` from `UserDetails` as the `Author` column instead of the `ID` of the user.
so the output will be as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Title] => Test News
            [Content] => hueheueheeueheu
            [CreatedAt] => 2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00
            [Author] => John Doe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Title] => gfdgdsfgfdg
            [Content] => sdfgfdgfdgfdgf
            [CreatedAt] => 2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00
            [Author] => John Doe
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 3
            [Title] => abcdef
            [Content] => ghijklm
            [CreatedAt] => 2018-03-29T00:00:00+00:00
            [Author] => Alice Smith
        )

)
```

This is my scheme at the moment:
[image: scheme]

How can I accomplish this without making a new relation from `News` to `UserDetails` (unless absolutely needed)?

Small sidenote:
I'm sorry if the flow in which I ask this question is a bit off, I have been looking for a solution for about two weeks now...

UPDATE: here is the schema file for this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<database name="MijnWerkwent">
  <table name="Users">
    <column name="ID" type="Integer" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="Username" type="Varchar" size="255" required="true"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_Users_ID">
      <unique-column name="ID"/>
    </unique>
  </table>
  <table name="UserDetails">
    <column name="UID" type="Integer" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="Firstname" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="Surname" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="Email" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="Address" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="PostalCode" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="Telephone" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="City" type="Varchar"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_UserDetails_UID">
      <unique-column name="UID"/>
    </unique>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Users" onDelete="CASCADE">
      <reference foreign="ID" local="UID"/>
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="Authtokens">
    <column name="ID" type="Integer" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="Token"/>
    <column name="UID" type="Integer" required="true"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_Authtokens_ID">
      <unique-column name="ID"/>
    </unique>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Users" onDelete="CASCADE">
      <reference foreign="ID" local="UID"/>
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="Passwords">
    <column name="ID" type="Integer" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="Seed" type="BigInt"/>
    <column name="Password" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="UID" type="Integer" required="true"/>
    <column name="TID" type="Integer" required="true"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_Passwords_ID">
      <unique-column name="ID"/>
    </unique>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_Passwords_TID">
      <unique-column name="TID"/>
    </unique>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Users" onDelete="CASCADE">
      <reference foreign="ID" local="UID"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Authtokens" onDelete="CASCADE">
      <reference foreign="ID" local="TID"/>
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="News">
    <column name="ID" type="Integer" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="Title" type="Varchar"/>
    <column name="Content" type="CLOB"/>
    <column name="Created_At" type="Timestamp"/>
    <column name="Author" type="Integer"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_News_ID">
      <unique-column name="ID"/>
    </unique>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Users" onDelete="SETNULL">
      <reference foreign="ID" local="Author"/>
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
</database>
```

Comment: Is UserDetails linked to Users with the delegate behavior? Or did you define the one-to-one relation manually?

Comment: I've created the one-to-one relation manually.
I also can't find a delegation in the `schema.xml`, so I think it's safe to assume I did not link them with the delegate behaviour